# How to populate JList with .java and .class files

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, filesystems, jlist

I'm creating an application that gets a list of .java and .class files from a chosen directory and places them in a JList. I am using Netbeans 7.1.2.

At the moment i have the files being retrieved and being placed into a `List<File>`. I have all the files in the list printing out but i cannot add them to the JList the is in my form.

this is how i am adding the files to the list

```
List<File> filesInDirectory = new ArrayList<>(); 

public List listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                        if(fileEntry.toString().toUpperCase().endsWith(".CLASS") || fileEntry.toString().toUpperCase().endsWith(".JAVA")){
                            filesInDirectory.add(fileEntry);
                            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
                        }
            }
        }

    return filesInDirectory;
}
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
for(File f : yourFileList) {
    model.addElement(f);
}

yourList.setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) object and add the files to this, then have the JList use this model. For more on this, please have a look at the [JList Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). You will likely want to create a ListCellRenderer so your file text displays properly.